# what is differece between landing page and one page website(template)

Tags: web

I can not understand what is difference between a landing page and a one page website (web template).
So, Kindly tell me what is difference between a landing page and one page website(template). and how can we differentiate in them.

thanks

Comment: If there is more than 1 page, it isn't a single page website. That's how you'll know.

Comment: thanks,  but i ask what is difference between a landing page and one page website.

Comment: google landing page and you should find answer

Comment: One has 1 page, the other has more. That's it. Besides, you did ask how to differentiate them. `and how can we differentiate in them`

Comment: Well, semantically, do you know what the words themselves mean?  One may reason that a "landing page" is a page on which a user "lands" and from which a user would access other pages.  And a "one page website" would probably be a website which has only one page.  What *exactly* are you asking and why?

Comment: I'm really starting to think this is trolling.

Answer (score 0):

Landing Page Sites -

- these sites are generally of format 1 page linked with another. User fall on home page and make an http:// req for next page.
- Remeber in this kind of sites generally each component are loaded each time http:// connection is made .
- Heavy traffic demanding.Because each component of the page is being reloaded every time http:// request fired.
- Slow and not that much dynamic in real life.

One page Sites -

- These sites are having one page only and that one page is collection of components which are handled by controllers .
- Each time you click on a component only that component is being updated instead of whole page .
- Some new Technologies like angular js  have reduced the work of server side processing in these kind of sites.
- Much of the work is being resolved at client side only.
- They are preferable over slow network , Because only relavent components are being updated .
- Consistent dynamics is at the core of these websites . But you may restrict it according to needs.